CoreText's CTRunDraw can't draw underline in iOS18?
I have run this demo code to draw a text with underline with CTRunDraw in both iOS17 & iOS18
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     // Flip the coordinate system
     CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
     CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
     CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

     NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20],
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],
                             NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleThick),
                             };

     // Make an attributed string
     NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello CoreText!" attributes:attrs];
    CFAttributedStringRef attributedStringRef = (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attributedString;

     // Simple CoreText with CTFrameDraw
     CTFramesetterRef framesetter =  CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedStringRef);
     CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(self.bounds,NULL);
     CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,CFRangeMake(0, 0),path,NULL);
     //CTFrameDraw(frame, context);

     // You can comment the line 'CTFrameDraw' and use the following lines
     // draw with CTLineDraw
     CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame);
     CGPoint lineOrigins[CFArrayGetCount(lines)];
     CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), lineOrigins);
     for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(lines); i++) {
         CTLineRef line = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, i);
         CGContextSetTextPosition(context,  lineOrigins[i].x, lineOrigins[i].y);
//         CTLineDraw(line, context);

         // You can comment the line 'CTLineDraw' and use the following lines
         // draw with CTRunDraw
         // use CTRunDraw will lost some attributes like NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName,
         // so you need draw it by yourself
         CFArrayRef runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
         for (int j = 0; j < CFArrayGetCount(runs); j++) {
             CTRunRef run = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runs, j);
             CTRunDraw(run, context, CFRangeMake(0, 0));
         }
     }
}

It turns out that the underline can be draw as expect in iOS17 , but not draw in iOS18.
Is it a feature of system bug ?
